# Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sales_flat_order' already exists

Tags: php, magento

I am installing magento in localhost XAMPP getting this error again and again with different log record number

Please reply i am learning magento first time..

> Error in file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\sql\sales_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sales_flat_order' already exists

Trace:

> `#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')`
>
> `#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.8')`
>
> `#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.8')`
>
> `#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()`
>
> `#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()`
>
> `#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()`
> `#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)`
>
> `#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\magento-downloader-1.7.0.0\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')`
>
> `#8 {main}`

Error log record number: 1003391393

Answer (score 1):

I think you should delete all the tables inside the magento databse 'sales_*' drop all tables starting from the sales_ keyword.

[base table already exist](http://explorephpcodes.blogspot.com/2014/05/magento-magento-error-base-table-or.html)

[magento upgrade](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/203438/)